Transferring Addons Across Blender Upgrades
What is the easiest way to store and transfer (and keep track of) your add-ons whenever upgrading Blender? Is it as easy as transferring a folder over to your newest version of Blender? How do YOU organize and keep track of your arsenal of add-ons? Thanks for your help.
(I am on a Mac, by the way... if that makes a difference. I'll be moving from 3.6 to 4.1 this week and then to 4.2 LTS when it comes out)
P.S.: A senodary question... Is the process affected if I want to keep at least 2 versions of Blender on my computer at all times? Thanks again.

Manual copy
By default, addons are installed in the scripts/addons subdirectory of Blender's user directory.
As per Blender’s Directory Layout - Blender 4.1 Manual


Linux: $HOME/.config/blender/4.1/
macOS: /Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/Blender/4.1/
Windows: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.1\


Note the version number in that path.
Transferring addons from one installation to another is as simple as copying the files from the script/addons of a version to another. But with caveats: it duplicates files on your storage, you might overwrite addons you already have or that are not compatible with the Blender version you copy them to. So you have to know your addons a bit, or trust you will have little to no issues and be able to quickly solve them when they occur.
When updating Blender
When you boot up a new version of Blender for the first time, the splash screen shows a button to import your settings from your previous Blender installation: it also copies addons.

Custom Script folder
An alternative way is to use the Script Directories in the Preferences:

Make yourself a directory where to install all your favorite addons. You can make a specific one for a specific Blender version, a general one for any version, ... As you wish.
Then add that directory in your Script Direcrories, and any addon installed there will be visible in that Blender installation where you set that Script Directory.
Advantages is that the folder may be easier to access, you are in total control of what gets there, and you can have as many folders for any purpose as you want.
And when updating Blender as mentioned above, it will copy the Script Directory from the last Blender installation too, so it will carry over, but without the downside of copying / making duplicates / overwriting anything.
Good to note that, when installing a new addon from Blender's Install Addon button, you need to set the target path to your Script Directory. Otherwise it defaults to the usual userdir/scripts/addons:

